# How to check network availability in action script?

Tags: actionscript

I want to check network and Internet availability in Action Script programming language. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest  ( YOUR URL HERE );
var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader ();
loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, handleLoaderComplete );
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, ldrStatus);
loader.load ( request );

protected function ldrStatus(evt:HTTPStatusEvent):void
{
 trace(evt.status)
}

protected function handleLoaderComplete(event:Event):void
{
  trace("COMPLETE");
}
```

try above code, evt.status should give 200, in success.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **AS3**, You can use 
[HTTPStatusEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html)